# Where to put default setting from "/sys" folder in Fedora 18?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, fedora, fedora-18

I have an SSD main disk and I want to use `noop` IO scheduler with it, like this:

```
echo noop > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

But this setting gets lost after reboot.
What is a right place to save this setting in Fedora 18? Or, may be, on linux in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a `udev` rule. Add a file to `/etc/udev/rules.d` with a rule that looks something like this:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_BUS}=="scsi", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="xxx", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="noop"
```

Obviously you should replace `xxx` with the correct serial number for the disk in question. You can find that, and other attributes you could match on, with:

```
udevadm info --path=/sys/block/sda --query=property
```

The advantage of using `udev` to do this, and matching on attributes like the disk serial number, is that it won't matter if it doesn't always appear at `sda`.

Comment: Additions to an answer: `ENV{ID_BUS}` is also customizable and should be "yyy"; when naming the rule file, try `udevadm test /sys/block/sda` to be sure that your rule is applied after all others.