# How to increase the bcache sequential_cutoff on Fedora startup

Tags: linux, fedora, udev, bcache

The bcache has `sequential_cutoff` parameter that is usually reachable at `/sys/block/bcache0/bcache/sequential_cutoff` and one can increase the level with following command:

```
echo 512M > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/sequential_cutoff
```

But after reboot the parameter is back to default 4.0M. How can I gain the same functionality at command above on Fedora startup?

Answer (score 4):

Udev rules allow tuning parameters as soon as kernel detects device. The bcache device can be recognized by its `MAJOR==252`. Just drop following file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and reboot:

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-bcache_sequential_cutoff.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{MAJOR}=="252", ATTR{bcache/sequential_cutoff}="512M"
```

Credits: the idea was inspired by answer to question about [persistence of queue scheduler for block devices](https://superuser.com/a/539863/22281).

Comment: I noticed via `udevadm test /sys/block/bcache0` that the major device group number bcache on my machine is 251 on my machine, so I had to modify the `ENV{MAJOR}` match for it to work.

Comment: This not a reliable way to do this. `ENV{MAJOR}` is unreliable. Instead use `KERNEL=="bcache*"`. Also, you can't set `sequential_cutoff` with something like "512M" as the value needs to be in bytes (eg. 536870912).